# The \alph counter representation has strange effects with the glossaries package

Tags: indexing, glossaries

This is a follow-up question here

[How could glossaries' numberlabel use the manually defined number of Sections(or other Sectional Units)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76173/how-could-glossaries-numberlabel-use-the-manually-defined-number-of-sectionsor/77638#comment165205_77638)

A suspect BUG. The parameter `\alph` doesn't work fine in my MAC OSX, when the counter is bigger than 6, in the section it is 2f, 2g, 2h, there will be something wrong. So I have to use `\newcommand{\alphstring}` and define `\GlsAddXdyAlphabet{alph}` from a to z manually same as greekstring and greek.

The mininal.tex:

I just copy  the     `\sectionalph{Linux}` of your solution code and then paste after it for some times.

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage[counter=section,xindy]{glossaries}

\newcounter{sectionalph}
\newcounter{sectiongreek}

\renewcommand{\thesectionalph}{\thesection\alph{sectionalph}}
\renewcommand{\thesectiongreek}{\thesection\greekstring{sectiongreek}}

\newcommand{\greekstring}[1]{%
  \ifcase\value{#1}\relax
  \or
   alpha%
  \or
   beta%
  \or
   gamma%
  \or
   delta%
  \or
   epsilon%
  \or
   zeta%
  \or
   eta%
  \or
   theta%
  \or
   iota%
  \or
   kappa%
  \or
   lambda%
  \or
   mu%
  \or
   nu%
  \or
   omicron%
  \or
   pi%
  \or
   rho%
  \or
   sigma%
  \or
   tau%
  \or
   upsilon%
  \or
   phi%
  \or
   chi%
  \or
   xi%
  \or
   psi%
  \or
   omega%
  \fi
}

\GlsAddXdyCounters{sectionalph}
\GlsAddXdyCounters{sectiongreek}

\GlsAddXdyAlphabet{greek}{"alpha" "beta" "gamma" "delta"
"epsilon" "zeta" "eta" "theta" "iota" "kappa" "lambda" "mu"
"nu" "omicron" "pi" "rho" "sigma" "tau" "upsilon" "phi"
"chi" "xi" "psi" "omega"}

\GlsAddXdyLocation{sectiongreek}{
  "arabic-numbers" "greek"}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\sectionalph}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{sectionalph}%
  \section*{\thesectionalph\quad #1}%
}

\newcommand{\sectiongreek}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{sectiongreek}%
  \section*{\thesectiongreek\quad #1}%
}

\newglossaryentry{Unix}{
name={Unix},
description={a multitasking, multi-user computer operating system}
}
\newglossaryentry{Unix-like}{
name={Unix-like},
description={operating system is one that behaves in a manner
similar to a Unix system}
}
\newglossaryentry{Linux}{
name={Linux},
description={Linux was originally developed as a free operating
system}
}
\newglossaryentry{FreeBSD}{
name={FreeBSD},
description={a free Unix-like operating system, an operating system}
}
\newglossaryentry{Windows}{
name={Windows},
description={a series of graphical interface operating systems}
}
\newglossaryentry{Mobile Operating System}{
name={Mobile Operating System},
description={the operating system that operates a smartphone...}
}


\begin{document}
\section{Unix}
Unix \glsadd{Unix} (officially trademarked as UNIX, sometimes also
written as Unix) is a multitasking, multi-user computer operating
system originally developed in 1969 by a group of AT\&T employees at
Bell Labs.

\section{Unix-like}
A Unix-like \glsadd{Unix-like}(sometimes referred to as UN*X or
*nix) operating system is one that behaves in a manner similar to a
Unix system, while not necessarily conforming to or being certified
to any version of the Single UNIX Specification.

\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.

\sectiongreek{FreeBSD}
FreeBSD \glsadd[counter=sectiongreek]{FreeBSD} is a free Unix-like operating system
descended from AT\&T UNIX via BSD UNIX.  Although for legal reasons
FreeBSD cannot be called "UNIX".

\section{Windows}
Microsoft Windows \glsadd{Windows}is a series of graphical interface
operating systems developed, marketed, and sold by Microsoft.

\sectiongreek{Mobile Operating System}
A mobile operating system \glsadd[counter=sectiongreek]{Mobile Operating System}, also
referred to as mobile OS, is the operating system that operates a
smartphone, tablet, PDA, or other digital mobile devices.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

There are pics:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for your particular document you will have to have a custom xindy module. Here's a sample xdy file called `test.xdy`:

```
;; xindy style file 'test.xdy'

; required styles

(require "tex.xdy")

; list of allowed attributes (number formats)

(define-attributes (("default"
 "glsnumberformat" 
 "sectionglsnumberformat"
 "sectionalphglsnumberformat"
 "sectiongreekglsnumberformat"
 "textrm" 
 "sectiontextrm"
 "sectionalphtextrm"
 "sectiongreektextrm"
 "textsf" 
 "sectiontextsf"
 "sectionalphtextsf"
 "sectiongreektextsf"
 "texttt" 
 "sectiontexttt"
 "sectionalphtexttt"
 "sectiongreektexttt"
 "textbf" 
 "sectiontextbf"
 "sectionalphtextbf"
 "sectiongreektextbf"
 "textmd" 
 "sectiontextmd"
 "sectionalphtextmd"
 "sectiongreektextmd"
 "textit" 
 "sectiontextit"
 "sectionalphtextit"
 "sectiongreektextit"
 "textup" 
 "sectiontextup"
 "sectionalphtextup"
 "sectiongreektextup"
 "textsl" 
 "sectiontextsl"
 "sectionalphtextsl"
 "sectiongreektextsl"
 "textsc" 
 "sectiontextsc"
 "sectionalphtextsc"
 "sectiongreektextsc"
 "emph" 
 "sectionemph"
 "sectionalphemph"
 "sectiongreekemph"
 "glshypernumber" 
 "sectionglshypernumber"
 "sectionalphglshypernumber"
 "sectiongreekglshypernumber"
 "hyperrm" 
 "sectionhyperrm"
 "sectionalphhyperrm"
 "sectiongreekhyperrm"
 "hypersf" 
 "sectionhypersf"
 "sectionalphhypersf"
 "sectiongreekhypersf"
 "hypertt" 
 "sectionhypertt"
 "sectionalphhypertt"
 "sectiongreekhypertt"
 "hyperbf" 
 "sectionhyperbf"
 "sectionalphhyperbf"
 "sectiongreekhyperbf"
 "hypermd" 
 "sectionhypermd"
 "sectionalphhypermd"
 "sectiongreekhypermd"
 "hyperit" 
 "sectionhyperit"
 "sectionalphhyperit"
 "sectiongreekhyperit"
 "hyperup" 
 "sectionhyperup"
 "sectionalphhyperup"
 "sectiongreekhyperup"
 "hypersl" 
 "sectionhypersl"
 "sectionalphhypersl"
 "sectiongreekhypersl"
 "hypersc" 
 "sectionhypersc"
 "sectionalphhypersc"
 "sectiongreekhypersc"
 "hyperemph" 
 "sectionhyperemph"
 "sectionalphhyperemph"
 "sectiongreekhyperemph")))

; user defined alphabets


 (define-alphabet "greek" ("alpha" "beta" "gamma" "delta" "epsilon" "zeta" "eta" "theta" "iota" "kappa" "lambda" "mu" "nu" "omicron" "pi" "rho" "sigma" "tau" "upsilon" "phi" "chi" "xi" "psi" "omega"))

; location class definitions

(define-location-class "section-numbers"
   ( :sep "{}{" "arabic-numbers" :sep "}" ) 
   :min-range-length 2
) 


(define-location-class "sectionalpha"
   (:sep "{}{"  "arabic-numbers" "alpha" :sep "}")) 

(define-location-class "sectiongreek"
   (:sep "{}{"  "arabic-numbers" "greek" :sep "}")) 

; define cross-reference class

(define-crossref-class "see" :unverified )
(markup-crossref-list :class "see"
   :open "\glsseeformat" :close "{}")

; define the order of the location classes
(define-location-class-order (
   "section-numbers"
   "sectionalpha"
   "sectiongreek"
   "see" ))

; define the glossary markup

(markup-index
   :open "\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}\glossarypreamble
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXglsnumberformat[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\glsnumberformat{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextsf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textsf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtexttt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\texttt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextmd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textmd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextsl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textsl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXtextsc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\textsc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\emph{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXglshypernumber[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\glshypernumber{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhyperrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hyperrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhypersf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hypersf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhypertt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hypertt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhyperbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hyperbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhypermd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hypermd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhyperit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hyperit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhyperup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hyperup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhypersl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hypersl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhypersc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hypersc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionXhyperemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{section}\hyperemph{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXglsnumberformat[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\glsnumberformat{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextsf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textsf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtexttt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\texttt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextmd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textmd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextsl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textsl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXtextsc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\textsc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\emph{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXglshypernumber[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\glshypernumber{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhyperrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hyperrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhypersf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hypersf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhypertt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hypertt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhyperbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hyperbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhypermd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hypermd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhyperit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hyperit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhyperup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hyperup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhypersl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hypersl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhypersc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hypersc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectionalphXhyperemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectionalph}\hyperemph{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXglsnumberformat[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\glsnumberformat{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextsf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textsf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtexttt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\texttt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextmd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textmd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextsl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textsl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXtextsc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\textsc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\emph{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXglshypernumber[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\glshypernumber{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhyperrm[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hyperrm{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhypersf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hypersf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhypertt[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hypertt{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhyperbf[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hyperbf{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhypermd[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hypermd{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhyperit[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hyperit{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhyperup[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hyperup{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhypersl[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hypersl{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhypersc[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hypersc{#2}}
\providecommand*\glsXsectiongreekXhyperemph[2]{\setentrycounter[#1]{sectiongreek}\hyperemph{#2}}
\begin{theglossary}\glossaryheader~n" 
   :close "%~n\end{theglossary}\glossarypostamble~n" 
   :tree)
(markup-letter-group-list :sep "\glsgroupskip~n")
(markup-indexentry :open "\relax\glsresetentrylist~n")
(markup-locclass-list :open "{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax "
   :sep ", " :close "}}")
(markup-locref-list :sep "\delimN ")
(markup-range :sep "\delimR ")

; define format to use for locations


(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXglsnumberformat" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionglsnumberformat")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXglsnumberformat" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphglsnumberformat")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXglsnumberformat" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekglsnumberformat")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextrm" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextrm")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextrm" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextrm")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextrm" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextrm")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextsf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextsf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextsf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextsf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextsf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextsf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtexttt" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontexttt")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtexttt" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtexttt")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtexttt" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektexttt")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextbf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextbf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextbf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextbf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextbf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextbf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextmd" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextmd")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextmd" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextmd")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextmd" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextmd")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextit" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextit")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextit" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextit")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextit" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextit")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextup" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextup")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextup" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextup")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextup" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextup")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextsl" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextsl")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextsl" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextsl")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextsl" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextsl")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXtextsc" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiontextsc")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXtextsc" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphtextsc")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXtextsc" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreektextsc")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXemph" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionemph")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXemph" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphemph")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXemph" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekemph")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXglshypernumber" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionglshypernumber")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXglshypernumber" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphglshypernumber")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXglshypernumber" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekglshypernumber")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhyperrm" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhyperrm")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhyperrm" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhyperrm")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhyperrm" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhyperrm")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhypersf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhypersf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhypersf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhypersf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhypersf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhypersf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhypertt" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhypertt")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhypertt" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhypertt")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhypertt" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhypertt")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhyperbf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhyperbf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhyperbf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhyperbf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhyperbf" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhyperbf")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhypermd" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhypermd")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhypermd" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhypermd")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhypermd" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhypermd")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhyperit" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhyperit")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhyperit" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhyperit")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhyperit" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhyperit")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhyperup" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhyperup")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhyperup" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhyperup")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhyperup" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhyperup")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhypersl" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhypersl")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhypersl" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhypersl")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhypersl" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhypersl")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhypersc" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhypersc")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhypersc" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhypersc")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhypersc" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhypersc")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionXhyperemph" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionhyperemph")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectionalphXhyperemph" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectionalphhyperemph")
(markup-locref :open "~n\glsXsectiongreekXhyperemph" 
 :close "" 
 :attr "sectiongreekhyperemph")

; define letter group list format

(markup-letter-group-list :sep "\glsgroupskip~n")

; letter group headings

(markup-letter-group :open-head "\glsgroupheading{"
   :close-head "}")

; additional letter groups

(define-letter-group "glsnumbers"
   :prefixes ("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9")
   :before "A")

; additional sort rules
```

Now your document needs to be modified so that it doesn't generate a custom module:

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage[counter=section,xindy]{glossaries}

\newcounter{sectionalph}
\newcounter{sectiongreek}

\renewcommand{\thesectionalph}{\thesection\alph{sectionalph}}
\renewcommand{\thesectiongreek}{\thesection\greekstring{sectiongreek}}

\newcommand{\greekstring}[1]{%
  \ifcase\value{#1}\relax
  \or
   alpha%
  \or
   beta%
  \or
   gamma%
  \or
   delta%
  \or
   epsilon%
  \or
   zeta%
  \or
   eta%
  \or
   theta%
  \or
   iota%
  \or
   kappa%
  \or
   lambda%
  \or
   mu%
  \or
   nu%
  \or
   omicron%
  \or
   pi%
  \or
   rho%
  \or
   sigma%
  \or
   tau%
  \or
   upsilon%
  \or
   phi%
  \or
   chi%
  \or
   xi%
  \or
   psi%
  \or
   omega%
  \fi
}

\setStyleFile{test}
\noist
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\sectionalph}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{sectionalph}%
  \section*{\thesectionalph\quad #1}%
}

\newcommand{\sectiongreek}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{sectiongreek}%
  \section*{\thesectiongreek\quad #1}%
}

\newglossaryentry{Unix}{
name={Unix},
description={a multitasking, multi-user computer operating system}
}
\newglossaryentry{Unix-like}{
name={Unix-like},
description={operating system is one that behaves in a manner
similar to a Unix system}
}
\newglossaryentry{Linux}{
name={Linux},
description={Linux was originally developed as a free operating
system}
}
\newglossaryentry{FreeBSD}{
name={FreeBSD},
description={a free Unix-like operating system, an operating system}
}
\newglossaryentry{Windows}{
name={Windows},
description={a series of graphical interface operating systems}
}
\newglossaryentry{Mobile Operating System}{
name={Mobile Operating System},
description={the operating system that operates a smartphone...}
}


\begin{document}
\section{Unix}
Unix \glsadd{Unix} (officially trademarked as UNIX, sometimes also
written as Unix) is a multitasking, multi-user computer operating
system originally developed in 1969 by a group of AT\&T employees at
Bell Labs.

\section{Unix-like}
A Unix-like \glsadd{Unix-like}(sometimes referred to as UN*X or
*nix) operating system is one that behaves in a manner similar to a
Unix system, while not necessarily conforming to or being certified
to any version of the Single UNIX Specification.

\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.
\sectionalph{Linux}
Linux \glsadd[counter=sectionalph]{Linux}was originally developed as
a free operating
system for Intel x86-based personal computers. It has since been
ported to more computer hardware platforms than any other operating
system.

\sectiongreek{FreeBSD}
FreeBSD \glsadd[counter=sectiongreek]{FreeBSD} is a free Unix-like
operating system
descended from AT\&T UNIX via BSD UNIX.  Although for legal reasons
FreeBSD cannot be called "UNIX".

\section{Windows}
Microsoft Windows \glsadd{Windows}is a series of graphical interface
operating systems developed, marketed, and sold by Microsoft.

\sectiongreek{Mobile Operating System}
A mobile operating system \glsadd[counter=sectiongreek]{Mobile
Operating System}, also
referred to as mobile OS, is the operating system that operates a
smartphone, tablet, PDA, or other digital mobile devices.

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

You'll get some multiple location reference warnings, but you can ignore them.

Comment: Where I put the test.xdy and how to use it? I can't understand what happened.

Comment: @WonderTree Suppose you have a document called `mydoc.tex` that uses the `glossaries` package. When you `latex` that document, the `glossaries` package creates a file called `mydoc.xdy` that sets up some default `xindy` styles. Sometimes a document has more complicated requirements in which case it's easier to create your own `.xdy` file and use that instead. So put `test.xdy` in the same directory as the document. `\noist` will prevent the generation of the custom `.xdy` file and `\setXdyStyle{test}` tells `makeglossaries` to use `test.xdy`.

Comment: @WonderTree The problem was caused by ambiguity. Does `c` indicate the letter `c` or the `roman` numeral for 100? Likewise for `i`. The custom file removes the default roman locations and adds the arabic-alpha and arabic-greek location styles.